# Reading from Datastore in Dataflow pipeline is slow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When reading data in from Datastore in my Dataflow pipeline, it seems like the job is not being distributed over the amount of available workers I have set for my job. Does Dataflow parallelize the read of Datastore data or is it doing it with a single worker?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, reads made by DatastoreIO use multiple workers to read in parallel. However, not all queries can be parallelized according to the documentation. For instance, queries that specify a limit or use an inequality filter. These queries would need to use a single worker to ensure correctness.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/datastore-io#reading-from-datastore